# What is the usual way of handling exceptions when dealing with callback functions?

Tags: c++, exception, callback, c++11

I have a non-blocking function (it returns immediately) that creates a new thread to parse some data:

```
boost::any Parse() throw(ParseException) {
  // parse something
}
typedef void (*HandlerFunc)(boost::any result);
void ParseAsync(HandlerFunc handler) {
  Parser me(*this);
  in_new_thread {
    boost::any result = me.Parse();
    handler(result);
  }
}
```

The problem is that `Parse` can throw an exception. What is the usual C++ way of handling these exceptions? Should I in some way "hand over" the exception to the handler function?

Comment: Throwing across threads is only addressed in the new C++11 standard. It's not part of the old C++ at all.

Comment: @Kerrek SB fortunately I am writing C++11 code.

Comment: Also, please avoid exception specifications (they are officially deprecated in C++11 for good reasons)

Comment: @Alexandre C. good point. I will keep it in the example in the question to make clear that `Parse` can throw an exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new C++11 standard support a number of facilities to ease thread programming.

The most interesting, in your case, are `std::future` and `std::promise`.

Note the `std::promise::set_exception_*` function. It allows you to channel an exception outside of its thread of origin (note `std::exception_ptr` has a shared pointer semantics). You can use `std::current_exception()` (in a `catch` statement) to get the required pointer.

Then note the `std::future::get` function: if the `promise` the `future` is extracted from had an exception instead of a value, then it will throw the exception.

This is the mechanism in place to channel exceptions from one thread to another.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I did something like that, I used a separate callback function that accepted a `std::exception const &` for exception handling. You need to be wary of object lifetimes though.